# Jquery DatePicker today button color

Tags: jquery, datepicker

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>    

 $("#datepicker").datepicker(
            {
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
                showButtonPanel: true,
                gotoCurrent: true
            });

        $.datepicker._gotoToday = function (id) {
            $(id).datepicker('setDate', new Date()).datepicker('hide').blur();
        };
```

I have today button in jquery datepicker.Today button is different color Close button is different color.Today button seems like light silver and close button seems dark silver.

How can i display "Today" button dark silver (same as close button)?